# can't get params from firebase function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, sendgrid

I'm currently trying to send a confirmation email with sendgrid API from a firebase function.

The API is not the problem though, it seems to work fine, my problem is that I can't get the child oncreate's value (Firebase function log):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'participant_id' of undefined
    at exports.SendEmail.functions.database.ref.onCreate.event (/user_code/index.js:15:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
    at next (native)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
    at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:716:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

And here's my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const SENDGRID_API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key;

const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);

exports.SendEmail = functions.database.ref('participants/{participant_id}').onCreate(event => {


  const participant_id = event.params.participant_id;

  const db = admin.database();

  return db.ref(`participants/${participant_id}`).once('value').then(function(data){

    const user = data.val();

    const email = {
      to: user.email,
      from: 'recrutement.cisssme16@ssss.gouv.qc.ca',
      subject: "Bienvenue au Blitz d'embauche 2018!",

      templateId: 'dd3c9553-5e92-4054-8919-c47f15d3ecf6',
      substitutionWrappers: ['<%', '%>'],
      substitutions: {
        name: user.name,
        num: user.num
      }
    };

    return sgMail.send(email)
  })
  .then(() => console.log('email sent to', user.email))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))

});
```

This is not my first firebase function. I even copied pasted previous working codes which worked fined and I still get an undefined value!

What's the problem here? Did firebase changed `event.params`?

Also my participant_id is an integer value (ex.: 3827), if that changes something.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of the function is wrong, take a look at this example on [Handle event data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data):

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.pushId, original);
    });
```

So just adjust your `onCreate` function and you'll be all set :)